# AlamoFire Sending Nil

Tags: ios, swift, api, request, alamofire

I'm sending a JSON request via Alamofire but, the function is sending nil. Even though I have verified that all items works as they should.

Helper Function:

```
 func requestServer(_ method: HTTPMethod,_ path: String,_ body: [String : Any]?,_ encoding: ParameterEncoding,_ headers: [String : Any]?,_ completionHandler: @escaping (JSON) -> Void){

        let url = baseURL?.appendingPathComponent(path)

        refreshTokenIfNeed {
            Alamofire.request(url!, method: method, parameters: body, encoding: encoding, headers: nil).responseJSON{ (response) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let jsonData = JSON(value)
                    completionHandler(jsonData)
                    break
                case .failure:
                    completionHandler(nil)
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Function sending Nil:

```
  func pickOrder(orderId: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
        let path = "api/driver/order/pick/"
        let header: [String: Any] = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + self.accessToken]

        let body: [String: Any] = [
            "order_id":"\(orderId)"
        ]
        print("header", header, "body", body)
        requestServer(.post, path, body, URLEncoding(), header, completionHandler)
    }
```

[image]

Any insight would help!

Comment: "Bearer " i think problem is you put space after Bearer .remove space than after check it

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do it. I've tried that. The reason I put it there is in Postman it requires a space after bearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line in your function named `requestServer`, you are sending **`headers nil`**, please pass the headers as well.

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: method, parameters: body, encoding: encoding, headers: nil).responseJSON{ (response) in
```

It should be like this,

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: method, parameters: body, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).responseJSON{ (response) in
```

Try it out.

**UPDATE**

Below code working

```
    let params = ["test":"123"]
    Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: nil).responseJSON { (test) in

    }
```

Comment: I would get an extra argument in my call. Since the requestServer function did not use "url!" changing it from nil would create an extra argument. How would I get around that?

Comment: No need to create extra argument, you have already in that function

Comment: That wouldn't work. Some of my functions are .get .Not all are .post

Comment: this is just suggestion, you can use get as well instead of post

Answer (score 1):

Pass `JSONEncoding.default` in method to send JSON as given:

```
requestServer(.post, path, body, JSONEncoding.default, header, completionHandler)
```

And pass header value in your header section:

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: method, parameters: body, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
```

And also check for the error. Print `print(response.error?.localizedDescription)` in `.failure`

Comment: I get the error that "Extra argument method in call." Specifically under the "method" variable in the Alamofire.request portion.

Comment: which alamofire version are you using?